# After restarting Win 7 BIOS doesn't ask me for password, why?

Tags: bios

I restarted my computer and surprisingly I don't get asked for the BIOS password... Afterwards I try shutting down and immediately turning the computer on, and then I need to give a password, as expected.
Why is that happening??

I've being googling and restart seems to be a coldboot... So, I don't understand what's going on

Comment: A restart from the OS is not a cold boot.  In general, a "cold boot" is when you're powering on from a powerless state.

Answer (score 1):

It's your machine that's doing that. Windows has no control over the computer's BIOS.

Thankfully this is (becoming) a standard feature, so that you're not bothered for a password on each reboot, only at power-on.

It helps immensely when working on and/or administering the machine from remote (via RDP or alike), as you may need to reboot it to accomplish your task.  This feature makes it so that it won't get stuck on the BIOS password that you can't see from remote (since the OS is offline during the reboot), allowing you to continue working from remote after requesting the reboot.